# If a vector $\mathbf{v}$ is rotated first around z-axis and then around a vector $\mathbf{u}$ to give $\mathbf{v'}$, find $\mathbf{u}$

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, rotations

Let vector $\mathbf{v}$ be a unit directional vector. We first rotate it around the $z-axis$ and then around a vector ($\mathbf{u}$) so that the resultant vector is $\mathbf{v'}$.

If the matrices defining the two rotations are $\mathbf{Q_u}$ and $\mathbf{Q_z}$, we can write:
$$ \mathbf{v'} = \mathbf{Q_u}.\mathbf{Q_z}.\mathbf{v}$$
If the cross product of $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v'}$ is given by $\mathbf{a} = \mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{v'}$, the dot product is $\mathbf{b} = \mathbf{v} . \mathbf{v'}$, and the skew symmetric matrix is $[\mathbf{a}]_{\times}$
, the transformation matrix would be given by:
$$\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{I} + [\mathbf{a}]_{\times} + [\mathbf{a}]_{\times}^2 . \frac{1}{1+\mathbf{b}}$$
where, $Q = Q_u . Q_z$, how do we find the vector $\mathbf{u}$ when only the vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{v'}$ are known?

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions. For any initial angle of rotation around the $z$-axis, there exists one $\mathbf{u}$ (or its negative) which can then move $\mathbf{Q_z \cdot v}$ to $\mathbf{v}'$ (unless it happens that $\mathbf{Q_z \cdot v} = \pm \mathbf{v}'$)

Comment: Of course. That makes sense.